# what is wrong with this code that should do whitebalancing in opencv

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I have this code:

```
vector<Mat> brg;
Mat output;
split(inputImage, brg);


double mb=mean(brg[0])[0];
double mg=mean(brg[1])[0];
double mr=mean(brg[2])[0];
cout << "mb "<< mb<< " mg "<< mg<< " mr "<< mr << endl;
double max=MAX(mb,MAX(mg,mr));

mb=max/mb;
mg=max/mg;
mr=max/mr;
brg[0]=brg[0] *mb;
brg[1]=brg[1] *mg;
brg[2]=brg[2] *mr;

{
    double mb=mean(brg[0])[0];
    double mg=mean(brg[1])[0];
    double mr=mean(brg[2])[0];
    cout << "mb "<< mb<< " mg "<< mg<< " mr "<< mr << endl;
}

merge(brg,output);
return output;
```

From mathematical pint of view, if I multiply a matrix by a number then its mean should be multiplied by that number, so I should get the same mb, mg, mr at the end of this function, but I am not getting.  the result that I am getting is as follow:

```
mb 166.891 mg 176.319 mr 158.288
mb 169.619 mg 176.319 mr 164.149
```

as can be seen, the mean changed but they are not equal, but they should all be equal to max.

Any reason that I am not getting this?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the data type of your matrix is something like CV_8UC3 which means the pixels are stored as unsigned 8 bit values.

When you scale, the scaled results are clipped to the range 0 to 255 so the mean does not change by the same scaling amount.

For example, suppose we had values:

```
0 , 64 , 64 , 128
```

and try to scale by a factor of 4.

The result would be:

```
0, 255, 255, 255
```

If this is the problem, then you may wish to use the [convertTo](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) method to change your matrix to a different data type (such as a floating point data type) with a greater dynamic range.

Note that the convertTo method also has an optional scale (and offset) so you can apply scaling while converting data type.